# Using NetBeans profiler with Guice classes

Tags: netbeans, profiler, guice

How can I use the profiler from NetBeans 6.8 or 6.9 (choosing 'entire application') with guice enhanced classes?

I am using google guice 2.0 (with warp persist 2.0-20090214) for some classes and wanted to profile those classes. But I cannot see a result for those classes. The only result I can see is for one method 'EnhancedClass.access$000' which is not very helpful. Other classes are working.

Does somebody know a workaround? Or know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The profiler produces these ugly results because there is no source code available to NetBeans for the enhanced classes. So you need to avoid that Guice needs to produce these classes in the first place by

- breaking the circular dependency (-ies) that cause them,
- or if you are using the AOP features of Guice I think you're out of luck

Comment: thanks for the update waldheinz! so I'm out of luck. but why yourkit display them correctly?